Freddy Krueger with syringe fingers
I remember that in a scene of a Freddy Krueger movie, there was something that appeared to me very creepy, in that sceene there was a girl with holes in her arm, resembling suckers or mouths or something like that, and Freddy had syringe fingers, and he injected her with what supposedly was drug, I think. Which movie is this scene from?

Nightmare on Elm Street 3: Dream Warriors features a scene where Taryn White comes across Freddie within her dream, where she has formed a punk persona to somehow bolster her confidence in defense against him.
Freddie, however, through occupying Taryn's mind knows of her past as a junkie, and as such his blades become syringes filled with a glowing narcotic.

Taryn's track marks become anthropomorphic at this point, and become mouths yearning for the nactoics to enter them. 

Freddie obliges pumping her veins with the liquid until her skin ruptures and she eventually dies of an incredibly graphic 'Overdose'.


A Nightmare on Elm Street 3: Dream Warriors
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Nightmare_on_Elm_Street_3:_Dream_Warriors
